# Java regex help

Tags: java, regex

Can somebody please show me how to do a Java regex that takes in a string and returns a string with all characters removed BUT a-z and 0-9?

I.e. given a string `a%4aj231*9.+` it will return `a4aj2319`

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\d is digit, \p{L} is a-z and A-Z.

```
str.replaceAll("[^\\d\\p{L}]", "");
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply..I just realized, what if I want to preserve spaces as well?

Comment: Just add any characters you don't want to replace within the square brackets.

Comment: \p{L} also matches a ton of other Unicode characters, such as Δ, ね, and 傻.  This expression will leave them all intact.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a-z and 0-9 but not A-Z then

```
str.replaceAll("[^\\p{Lower}\\p{Digit}]", "");
```

Comment: I didn't go with \w because that includes underscores as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
str = str.replaceAll("[^a-z0-9]+", "");
```

If you also meant to include uppercase characters, then you could use

```
str = str.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]+", "");
```

or the slightly leeter

```
str = str.replaceAll("[_\\W]+", "");
```